# Add post/comment angular js in WP Rest Api

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, api, rest

I have a problem with posting data to the WP Rest API in combination with my Angular webApp. My first guess is that I am not posting the data in the right format.

My function to post the data is as follows: (some data is static for test purposes only)

```
 $scope.submitComment = function () {
var d = new Date();
commentForm = [
  {
    'author_email': $scope.email,
    'author_name': $scope.name,
    'author_url': 'http://www.domain.com',
    'content': $scope.comment,
    'date': '2015-11-29T20:10:36',
    'date_gmt': '2015-11-29T19:10:36',
    'karma': '',
    'parent': 0,
    'post': $scope.postID,
    'status': 'approved',
    'type': 'comment'
  }
];
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://www.domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=' + $scope.postID,
  data: commentForm
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  console.log(response);
}, function errorCallback(response) {

});

$scope.showCommentForm = false;
$scope.showCommentButton = true;
```

};

When I log commentForm, all the properties are set. But none of them are inserted into the database. What am I doing wrong? The response of the $http Post is a 201, so it seems successful.